# Comparison Shiny / rmarkdown::render_site() & flexdashboard

Tags: r, r-markdown, shiny, flexdashboard

A high level question from someone new to the activity of building websites based on R code:

I am trying to understand the relationship between Shiny and the facilities offered by rmarkdown to render interactive and/or web content (e.g., using `rmarkdown::render_site()`, `flexdashboard`).

What triggered this question is reading on the [`rmarkdown` documentation](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-14.html) that:

> R Markdown documents are a perfect platform for interactive content.

Plus seeing [these great dashboards](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/) made with `flexdashboard`.

To navigate the various options available to building websites based on R code, I would like to know:

1. how `Shiny` articulates with the capabilities offered by
   `rmarkdown`?
2. how `Shiny` programming compares, in terms of
   ease/scalability/flexibility, with `rmarkdown` / `flexdashboard`?

I have done a fairly big `shiny` app and want to know whether I should try to migrate to e.g., `flexdahboard`.

Answer (score 2):

Shiny came first, and after a while they added some of shiny's capabilities to markdown. In order to use interactive markdowns, notice that you need to use `runtime: shiny` which means that it DOES need shiny to run on the backend, it's no longer than a pure standalone HTML document.

However, what I just said doesn't explain anything about what you asked, just wanted to point that out! This is indeed a great question, and there is an [open issue on shiny's github](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1497) to try to explain the difference between them, and other similar formats, because I agree it's very overwhelming to see all these options and have to choose which one to go with.  Just to add to the complexity - you can in fact write/embed shiny apps inside Rmd documents :)

(I couldn't submit this as a comment because it's too long)

Comment: Thanks for this. I just discovered `flexdashboard`. Is this what you had in mind when saying that one can "write/embed shiny apps inside Rmd documents"? Or is there yet another option? (i also edited my original question to introduce `flexdashboard`into the comparison)

Comment: That's not what I meant. You can embed shiny apps in regular Rmd documents too http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_embedded_shiny.html